# Tab not printing in print statement

Tags: java, swing

I am developing a Java project where I am required to print a string in a dialog box. Following is the code snippet

```
String businfo = "Busno" + "\t" + "Source" + "\t" + "Destination" + "\t" +  "Date" + "\t" + "Fare" + "\n";
int n = TicketBooking.dis.readInt();
for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
    Bus b = (Bus)TicketBooking.ois.readObject();
    businfo += b.busno + "\t" + b.source + "\t" + b.destination + "\t" + b.date + "\t" + b.fare + "\n";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,businfo);
```

[Dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydmCG.png)

String that I print does not have tabs. What is wrong with "\t"?

Comment: I expected `System.out.println()` after reading `not printing in print statement`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,businfo)` to

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,new JTextArea(businfo))`

JOptionPane is a GUI component so you should put another GUI component better suited for handling text in it rather that a raw string so that the formatting can't get messed up.